# xml parsing in winforms get plain text

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

In the below xml file:

```
    <SVCs>
         <SVC>
              <id>001</id>
              <request>Send SMS SVC 001 Request</request>
              <reposne>Send SMS SVC 001 Response</reposne>
         </SVC>
         <SVC>
               <id>002</id>
               <request>Send SMS SVC 002 Request</request>
               <reposne>Send SMS SVC 002 Response</reposne>
        </SVC>
    </SVCs>
```

I need to search for id say 002, and get the request and response for the same in form of plain text. i am working in winforms C# .net 4.0. How do i achieve this?
I am using XMLDocument namespace to parse through the document.

I am really new to XML library and i think this is one of the basic questions. I really googled a lot but couldn't find how to get the inner text by searching for a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use linq2xml

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var svc = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//SVC[id='002']");

var req = svc.Element("request").Value;
var resp = svc.Element("reposne").Value;
```

or

```
var svc = xDoc.Descendants("SVC")
              .First(s => s.Element("id").Value == "002");
```

PS: I keep the same typo `reposne`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood your question right but you get inner text like this:

```
XmlReader subReader = _reader.ReadSubtree();
subReader.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using linq!

```
  XElement xmldoc=   XElement.Load(new StringReader(@"<SVCs>
         <SVC>
              <id>001</id>
              <request>Send SMS SVC 001 Request</request>
              <reposne>Send SMS SVC 001 Response</reposne>
         </SVC>
         <SVC>
               <id>002</id>
               <request>Send SMS SVC 002 Request</request>
               <reposne>Send SMS SVC 002 Response</reposne>
        </SVC>
    </SVCs>"));




         var result = xmldoc.Elements("SVC").Where(e=>e.HasElements).Elements("id").Single(x=>x.Value=="002");
```

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand you could use Linq2XML too

```
var SVCs = XElement.Load("demoFile.xml");

var result = from svc in SVCs.Elements()
                where svc.Element("id").Value == "002"
                select svc;

foreach (var entry in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry);
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Element("request").Value);
}
```